# I'm unable to trace the error for a function

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

I am having trouble in debugging the error in this code, and not understanding where exactly I am going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class man
{
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
public:
    int data(void);
    void initialize(int,int,int);
};
int man::data(void)
{
    return (age*height)/weight;
};
void man::initialize(initial_age,initial_height,initial_weight)
{
    age = initial_age;
    height = initial_height;
    weight = initial_weight;
};

int main()
{
    man tim,crook;
    tim.initialize(19,178,55);
    crook.initialize(28,171,71);

    cout << "THE DATA IS AS SHOWN FOR tim" << tim.initialize() << endl;
    cout <<"THE DATA IS AS SHOWN FOR crook" << crook.initialialize() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the information about the error you encountered.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Initial_age,initial_height,initial_weight not declared in this scope is the error.

Comment: as I thought. See my answer.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko The output statements as well has an error which says no matching functions. i am sure i am passing three integers which is set as private and accessing it through the member functions

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Yes i did accepted it, but do you see some problem with my output statements?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko I found my mistake its fixed. i was calling the wrong function, i had to call  tim.data(), instead i was calling tim,initialise()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a naked eye I noticed an error in the implementation of `man::initialize` method. It has no types for its arguments. Add `int` types.

```
void man::initialize(int initial_age, int initial_height, int initial_weight)
{
    age = initial_age;
    height = initial_height;
    weight = initial_weight;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, blindly i wrote it and was wondering what could be wrong.

Comment: @vinod, consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.